# Azure Text Translator v3.0 doesn't work from March 8

Tags: azure-text-translation

My Android app is using text translator API v3.0 for 2 years but somehow it didn't work from March 8.
I got code 401 but I verified the secure key on Azure dashboard it's correct.
It also reported failure when I tried on Azure dashboard as image below. Does that mean something wrong with my account?
Subscription ID is 78e39975-800d-45f8-a109-c6b7a30076c8
Please help.

Thanks! Here I have attached a image.
[image]

---

I did try with REST API but got following error:
Response{protocol=h2, code=401, message=, url=https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=zh-Hans&to=en}

I attached the metrics on Azure Dashboard. It doesn't ecceed TPS limit for sure.

My Android app uses REST API for text, and speechSDK for Speech（'com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech:client-sdk:1.34.0').
This app has worked well for more than 2 years but suddenly Text Translation got failure from March 8. Considering the speechSDK still works, I think my account payment should be good.

I'm curious about what happened on March 8th but have no idea. :(

Any clue could be helpful for us. Thanks for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGDW2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us and reporting this issue.

The portal option is just a test feature and also portal testing isn't considered for production.

Could you please test using the Translation [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/quickstart-text-rest-api?tabs=csharp) or using [the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/quickstart-text-sdk?pivots=programming-language-csharp) and check if you encounter the same issue ?

You need to ensure that you have Allowed access from ***All Networks*** for your Azure Translator resource as shown below:
[image]

Also if you wish to make this work on the portal, you need to [***capture the HAR traces***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/capture-browser-trace) and identify the REST API call and the error it is failing with.

On a side note: if you encounter an error prompting you to retry, typically this might be due to exceeding the [***TPS limit***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/service-limits) on your translator resource. When the current transactions per second limit is surpassed, the resource cannot handle additional requests. To address this issue, users can consider upgrading their resource's pricing tier to increase the TPS limit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have added some new information.

Comment: please refer to ,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGDW2.png. I did try with REST API but got following error: Response{protocol=h2, code=401, message=, url=https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=zh-Hans&to=en}

I attached the metrics on Azure Dashboard. It doesn't ecceed TPS limit for sure. SDK version:（'com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech:client-sdk:1.34.0'). This app has worked well for more than 2 years but suddenly Text Translation got failure from March 8. Considering the speechSDK still works, I think my account payment should be good.

Comment: curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: key' -H 'X-ClientTraceId: xxxx' -H 'Content-Length: 28' -i 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=zh-Hans' --data '[{"Text":"a"}]'
HTTP/2 401 
date: Tue, 26 Mar 2024 08:25:05 GMT

x-requestid: bae1f050-7193-4626-b928-1bf20874667e.JAEA.0326T0825
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
{"error":{"code":401001,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please confirm the Networking section shown in my above comment ? is that set to Allow access from All Networks ?

Comment: Also try to pass the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region header and check if that makes a difference.


Please confirm if you have any firewall / proxy within your network which might be stripping the header from our your outgoing request.  Could you please try the same from a different network ? Hope this helps.

Comment: We have tried different network via VPN but got same error. 
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region is optional right? My Location/Region is "global". I am not sure what string shall I put in it (I am from China).

Comment: Thank you for your help. We adjusted the pricing tier, and the issue has been resolved.